# Dynamically load template files to Rythm? (without directory setting)

Tags: java, template-engine, rythm

I want to be able to do something like

```
// be able to replace this section
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("home.template", "resources"); // foo.html and bar.html (foo invoke bar)
Rythm.init(map);
System.out.println(Rythm.render("foo.html", "World"));

// with this section
Rythm.put("foo.html", fooTemplateStr);//dynamically add/replace foo.html to template repository
Rythm.put("bar.html", barTemplateStr);//dynamically add/replace bar.html to template repository
System.out.println(Rythm.render("foo.html", "World"));
```

I am building a simple blog engine that allows the user to set/alter the templates via a web interface. But I am required to have the templates fixed in a directory or jar file with Rythm, can I load them dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the source code of http://fiddle.rythmengine.org/ at https://github.com/rythmengine/rythmfiddle. Specifically checkout these files:

- https://github.com/rythmengine/rythmfiddle/blob/master/app/models/InMemoryResourceLoader.java
- https://github.com/rythmengine/rythmfiddle/blob/master/app/models/CodeFile.java
- https://github.com/rythmengine/rythmfiddle/blob/master/app/models/Code.java